# Adding values from a file to a HashMap with a Map inside

Tags: java

I'm trying to read from a package of txt files and adding the values to my HashMap. I'm trying to split the values using split(","). Then depending if the gender value is F or M to add to the right Map.

girlsByYear.put(number, (name, value)); This code gives me a compile error saying "The Field String.value is not visible", which I don't understand because it seems to be able to see number and name. I'm also new to using HashMaps and other sorts of Sets. I'm not even sure if that is the right syntax to put values into a map inside of a HashMap.

These are the HashMaps I'm using:

```
HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>> girlsByYear = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();
HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>> boysByYear = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();

public void load() throws FileNotFoundException {

    File dir = new File("src/data");
    File [] files = dir.listFiles();

    // for each file in the directory...
    for (File f : files)
    {   
        Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
        while (input.hasNext()) {

              String line = input.next();
              String [] details = line.split(",");

              String name = details[0];
              String gender = details[1];
              String value = details[2];

              if(gender == "F") {
                  girlsByYear.put(number, (name, value));
              }
              else {
                  boysByYear.put(number, (name, value));
              }

            }

        number++;

    }
}
```

Comment: as an aside, you'll want to compare with `"F".equals(gender)`. not using the `==` operator.

Comment: the value to `girlsByYear.put(number, (name, value));` and `boysByYear.put(number, ...)`should be a map as your maps are `HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>` either way there's many things you can improve upon here.

Comment: All I have read so far is putting values into a HashMap, I can't find anything to read to tell me how to add to a Map inside of a HashMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check if the nested map exists and if not, create it. Then you can add the value by retrieving the nested map and putting an object inside of that map. eg:

```
if (!girlsByYear.containsKey(number)) {
    girlsByYear.put(number, new HashMap<>());
}
girlsByYear.get(number).put(name, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to improve @flake answer, if you use Java 8 you can you this:

```
girlsByYear.putIfAbsent(number, new HashMap<>());
girlsByYear.get(number).put(name, value);
```

Or you can try Guava library (a widely used library from Google), it has a data structure called Table:

```
Table<String, String, Integer> girlsByYear = HashBasedTable.create();
//...
girlsByYear.put(number, name, value);
```

You can check tutorial how to use Table here https://www.baeldung.com/guava-table

Comment: Put if absent is going to be less efficient if called many times. Every iteration you create a new hashmap which gets discarded. A better solution would be compute if absent which takes a lambda, but does not necessarily get executed